# Stuck With a Follower

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have the quest to bring followers to Delphine. I have a follower already, Aela the huntress (my wife), but she won't be recruited. I try getting others but I have Aela so I can't. I don't know how to leave her.

Comment: When you open dialog with her and tell her "It's time for us to part ways" (meaning she should not follow you anymore) what happens?

Comment: It doesnt give me the chance to say "Its time for us to part our ways."

Comment: Have you messed with the game console by any chance?

Comment: It might be because you're married to her. The dialogue options do change a bit between regular companion and spouse. I'm not totally sure though

Comment: Before I think it didnt let me leave her before I was married. And no, I havent messed with the console.

Comment: Did you recruit her as a follower or is she following you as part of a Companions Quest like [Glory of the Dead](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Glory_of_the_Dead) or [The Silver Hand](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Silver_Hand)? If it's the latter, you just need to complete the quest. She will join you for the latter half of both of those quests. I thought you needed to finish the Companions quests to marry her, though, so that might not be it. (One way to tell is to try killing her. If she's still essential that implies the Companions questline isn't complete.)

Comment: I completed all companions quest and killing her doesnt work. I even shouted her off the throat of the world and she didnt die.

Comment: Aela is considered "essential" by the game.  She cannot die.  @spugsley:  Marriage should not have any effect on the follower options.  I'm married to Jordis, but I still have the same follow/part ways/trade/etc. options as I did before.

Comment: Do it my way take her to the throat of the world and FUS RO DAH HER ASS TO OBLIVION

Comment: My bad, @Iszi is right about Aela staying essential after Companions.

Answer (score 4):

Aela isn't a companion at this point she is considered a quest giver which means she will follow you until whatever mission involving her is completeted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on PC, all you have to do is open console by hitting this key "~" and then type "set playerfollowercount to 0". this will dismiss all your followers, some followers you did not even know were following you. This may or may not work but it is worth a try. After typing press enter and recruit the follower you want recruited.